# Go to next frame on Photoshop timeline

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to use a shortcut to go to next (or back) frame on photoshop timeline.
On adobe guide, the shortcut should ne arrow right or left.
BUT I dont know why it's not working for me.
I can't even find this action on the shorcut menu of photoshop, to edit it for exemple.

If someone have a solution it will be awesome, 
THX

Comment: So neither the left arrow nor page up key make it go left a frame? And neither the right arrow nor the page down key make it go right? If they don't, that sounds like it needs tech support and is off topic here. Try restarting the application and perhaps your computer

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable timeline shortcuts first in order for them to work:

[image]

Comment: Just to add, this context menu appears from that hamburger menu on timeline top right corner (left from close tab group on that image above)

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Photoshop CC 2015, you'll find what you need in:

Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts

1. In the dropdown for "Shortcuts For:" you choose Panel Menus
2. Scroll down to and expand "Timeline (Frames)" > Go To > Next Frame
3. Input your Keyboard Shortcut
4. Click Accept
5. Click OK

[image: Screenshot of "Keyboard Shortcuts and Menus" Photoshop CC 2015]